# Number theoretic transform multiplication is shifted

Tags: fft, multiplication, polynomials, ntt

I've been working on code to multiply polynomials using NTT (FFT), and I made 2 different implementations, and used existing ones to validate, for example: https://www.nayuki.io/page/number-theoretic-transform-integer-dft, https://github.com/iblue/ntt.

The problem is that all results seem to be shifted once to the left (multiplied by x) like this:

```
0 0 1 1 (x + 1)
*
0 0 1 1 (x + 1)
=
1 2 1 0 (1x^3 + 2x^2 + x) // Should be 0 1 2 1
```

Also, the trivial case 1*1 is wrong the same way:

```
0 0 0 1 (1)
*
0 0 0 1 (1)
=
0 0 1 0 (x) // Should be 0 0 0 1 (1)
```

I have no clue why this is happening, and it is not mentioned in any of the articles I've read so far.

What am I missing?

Comment: It seems like that example code which you provided (from github) assumes that data is provided in reverse order from yours - power's coefficients go from left to right for lowest to highest. For example (1, 2, 0, 0) will be 2*x + 1.

Comment: Hm.. you're right, I didn't see it. I was sure the higher coefficients get the low exponent twiddle factors, I didn't even look there. Thanks.

Comment: I agree with @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets's answer. When using my NTT implementation, you should put the coefficient for x^0 at index 0, in other words, the left side of the vector.